# Gson IllegalStateException Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING when data type is CharSequence

Tags: java, kotlin, gson

Suppose I have a simple data class

```
data class Car(var make: String)
```

and a Json String

```
val json = "[{'make':'foo'}, {'make':'bar'}]"
```

When I use `Gson` to deserialize the string

```
val carList : MutableList<Car> = gson.fromJson(json, Array<Car>::class.java).toMutableList()
```

It works as expected. But when I change the data type of `make` in `Car` to `CharSequence`

```
data class Car(var make: CharSequence)
```

And with GsonBuilder

```
val builder = GsonBuilder()
builder.registerTypeAdapter(CharSequence::class.java, object : InstanceCreator<CharSequence> {
    override fun createInstance(type: Type?): CharSequence {
        return String()
    }
})
gson = builder.create()
```

I got `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 11 path $[0].make`

Have been struggling to make it work with `CharSequence` type already, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an appropriate `JsonDeserializer`. Not `InstanceCreator`. For example:

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(CharSequence::class.java, object : JsonDeserializer<CharSequence> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): CharSequence = json?.asString ?: ""
})
```

Comment: It works, thx so much for the quick solution. But why the error message told me to try InstanceCreator when I did not have InstanceCreator? Weird.